# Объект не поддерживает свойство или метод "assign" в IE11

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel

Настроил webpack + babel следующим образом

**webpack.config.js**

```
...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
...
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": ["lodash", "transform-object-rest-spread"],
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": [
        "> 4%",
        "ie 11",
        "safari 8"
      ]
    }],
    "react",
    "react-optimize"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
    }
  }
}
```

Запускаю в chrom все ок, в IE 11 выдает ошибку

> Объект не поддерживает свойство или метод "assign"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-assign
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-object-assign"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В Node JS добавь пакет

```
npm install --save-dev core-js
```

После добавь в файл, где используется object.assing

```
import 'core-js/fn/object/assign';
```

Инфа отсюда:
https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/wiki/Supporting-Internet-Explorer-11-(or-older)